# HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA coding/failures with Disk IO

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Is it possible for the related c++ functions to fail or timeout due to high disk i/o or other server related issues? I know running out of memory could cause these to fail using `LocalAlloc` and the like, but I feel I'm seeing errors during anti-virus runs or something similar on the C Drive. The code only traps `!ERROR_SUCCESS`, so I dont know what error is being thrown in the production code as of yet.

This is intentionally a very general question. I'm just looking for some experienced tips/gotchas that people have seen dealing with performance counter data. Are there any other common ways these could fail when normally they run ok?

Thanks!

```
RegOpenKeyEx
RegQueryValueEx
```

Edit:
Recent changes: Going from Server 2003 to Server 2008.

Comment: One gotcha I found is a problem with reading a key.. you should specify whether you are reading a 64bit key from 32bit system or vice-versa: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129(v=vs.85).aspx MAYBE it might be the same for you.. not sure.. but for me, it just kept saying key not found but returned successful :l

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames Nice tip. However, this is an issue that fails infrequently. It reads PID data every few seconds 24/7, but only fails once every week or two. The main change was bringing our product from 2003 to 2008 Server.